# Определить POPUP окно и получить доступ из него к родительскому

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте!

Такой вопрос: как с помощью js/jquery определить, было ли окно открыто обычным образом или как POPUP, и если второе — как получить доступ из POPUP к элементам родительского окна?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прочтите [window.opener](http://javascript.ru/window.opener):

```
if( window.opener ){
   // PopUp
}
```